# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook, dllimport

I want to import some function from sklearn module :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

But it return this ImportError :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3fb1a94f6848> in <module>
      3 import scipy.io
      4 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
----> 5 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
      6 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
      7 

c:\users\jules\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     73     from . import __check_build
     74     from .base import clone
---> 75     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     76 
     77     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error

c:\users\jules\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py in <module>
     10 import importlib
     11 
---> 12 from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
     13 
     14 

ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

In fact, I checked the `utils` folder and don't found `_openmp_helpers.pyx`.

Recently, I must changed from macOs to Windows. I didn't have this problem with macOs. I installed sklearn using `pip install sklearn`, and I'm using jupyter notebook for this student project.

```
pip -V : 19.3.1
python --version : Python 3.7.5
```

Comment: To help you we need code. Please add it to the question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it only through getting back to one of the previous versions of scikit-learn (namely 0.20.2 which I kept with an older installation of python). Try downgrading sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, but I don't think it's the best way to fix the problem: no ? At least, it will help me to go forward in my project, but I'm still attentive to an other solution, without using Anaconda.